# How can I fix a broken AVI file?

Tags: video, ubuntu-9.10, avi

I have a broken AVI, it won't play in VLC, Xine or MPlayer.

I tried Handbrake (reads the file and resets the source to None), OggConvert, Avidemux and mencoder fail to read the file, I cannot seem to reencode this file.

I suspect the header info is corrupt, is there a way to get the a/v streams out with a missing header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one other suggestion is [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/), it can copy the video from an AVI to another container format like ogg or mov without transcoding, but whether that will work or not probably depends on what is wrong with the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try and opening in [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/); perhaps that will have more luck reincoding.

Comment: Virtualdub couldn't open the file either. I copied the header from another AVI, hoping the streams would reconstruct, which it did, with many warnings. VD eventually crashed hard.